# VerticalGridFragment Endless scroll

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm creating android tv app but I don't know how to implement endless scroll in `Verticalgridfragment`, i use `ArrayObjectAdapter`, can someone help me do that?

Comment: are you use recyclerview?

Comment: @ Farzad Sarseifi: no, i use default view in verticalgridfragment

Comment: see this link:
http://corochann.com/verticalgridfragment-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-19-718.html

Comment: yep, i follow that tutorial, but i don't see endless scrolling implementation :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd love to give you a full answer with oodles of code samples but I'm not at my work computer. Basically you'll implement the `onItemSelected` listener in your `Browse`/`RowsFragment` (it should be something like `setOnItemViewSelectedListener()` from your fragment).

Then you do a check to see if the currently selected element is within [5 or 10 or 15 elements from the end of the list](https://github.com/hitherejoe/Vineyard/blob/353b448633970c23eb7a67f71874006914b4e92c/app/src/main/java/com/hitherejoe/vineyard/ui/fragment/MainFragment.java#L329). If it's within that threshold, then make the request for the next page of your list and call `addAll()` on your adapter when you get the next page. You can optionally show a ["loading card"](https://github.com/hitherejoe/Vineyard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hitherejoe/vineyard/ui/adapter/PaginationAdapter.java) while the next page request is in flight and remove it when you get your data.

I based my implementation off of [this open source project](https://github.com/hitherejoe/Vineyard) - while it's not perfect it should be enough of a code sample to get your started.

Comment: setOnItemViewSelectedListener() isn't called when item is hovered/ or being zoomed inside a class that extends RowsFragment. but setOnItemViewClickedListener works perfectly.Any solution?